# Equivalent of python enumerate in objective C

Tags: python, objective-c

I want to print a playlist. Here is how I would do it in python:

```
playlist = ['Classical Song', 'Rock Song', 'New Song']
for num, item in enumerate(playlist):
    print '%s) %s' % (num+1, item)

1) Classical Song
2) Rock Song
3) New Song
```

How would I do the same in Objective-C? Here is what I have so far:

```
NSArray *playlist = @[@"Classical Song", @"Rock Song", @"New Song"];
for (NSString *item in playlist) {
    NSLog(@"?) %@", item);
}

2014-08-23 15:56:34.421 Music[16332:303] ?) Classical Song
2014-08-23 15:56:34.423 Music[16332:303] ?) Rock Song
2014-08-23 15:56:34.423 Music[16332:303] ?) New Song
```

How would I change the above to get the numbers as well in the enumeration loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for in loop doesn't provide the index, but there is a method enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: that does.

```
NSArray *playlist = @[@"Classical Song", @"Rock Song", @"New Song"];
[playlist enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       NSLog(@"%ld) %@", idx+1, obj);
}];
```